Azure Appservice for Django fails with Azure Devops Pipeline
I have an appservice running on Azure in a Linux environment.
I try to associate it with a Azure Devops Pipeline so I can have CI/CD for the repositories & branches on Github.
I want the builds to occur on Azure Pipeline & Azure infrastructure, not Github Actions.
I have tried all other suggestions including following environment variables on App Service :
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true

WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=~18

WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=true

Here is the logs that I receive from the Kudu / Azure Devops Pipeline / AppService logs :
/home/LogFiles/2024_08_14_ln1xsdlwk0000K3_docker.log  (https://project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_08_14_ln1xsdlwk0000K3_docker.log)
2024-08-14T23:51:45.168Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for 10.1.0.6:13209/appsvc/python:3.10_20240619.2.tuxprod
2024-08-14T23:51:45.179Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Seconds
2024-08-14T23:51:45.223Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2024-08-14T23:51:45.223Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8000 --name project-app-development_0_f2e0544d -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=project-app-development -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=project-app-development.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=3f627dbbecdaed255d87aa9c3e8f1448758df1cdff41f5e14b114384ea9b244a appsvc/python:3.10_20240619.2.tuxprod gunicorn -b :$PORT project.wsgi
2024-08-14T23:51:45.223Z INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2024-08-14T23:51:45.893Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container project-app-development_0_f2e0544d for site project-app-development
2024-08-14T23:51:49.043Z ERROR - Container project-app-development_0_f2e0544d for site project-app-development has exited, failing site start
2024-08-14T23:51:49.057Z ERROR - Container project-app-development_0_f2e0544d didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-08-14T23:51:49.063Z INFO  - Stopping site project-app-development because it failed during startup.
/home/LogFiles/2024_08_14_ln1xsdlwk0000WT_default_docker.log  (https://project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/2024_08_14_ln1xsdlwk0000WT_default_docker.log)
2024-08-14T00:05:39.611783454Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-08-14T00:05:39.611788754Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
2024-08-14T00:05:39.611793955Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
2024-08-14T00:05:39.611799355Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-08-14T00:05:39.611804655Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
2024-08-14T00:05:39.611810055Z [2024-08-14 00:05:39 +0000] [83] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 83)
2024-08-14T00:05:39.756375163Z [2024-08-14 00:05:39 +0000] [49] [ERROR] Worker (pid:83) exited with code 3
2024-08-14T00:05:39.758705055Z [2024-08-14 00:05:39 +0000] [49] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
2024-08-14T00:05:39.758726256Z [2024-08-14 00:05:39 +0000] [49] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Here is my startup command on Azure AppService Configuration :
gunicorn -b :8000 project.wsgi



% cat app.yaml 
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT project.wsgi

# service: "project-ai-266410"
service: "default"
handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
# directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  secure: always

# This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
# required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
# the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always%   


% cat ./project/wsgi.py 
"""
WSGI config for project project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()

Here is my github workflow file :
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions
# More info on Python, GitHub Actions, and Azure App Service: https://aka.ms/python-webapps-actions

name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - project-app-development

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 543-azure-based-secrets
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: '3.12'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv antenv
          source antenv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_5DF5B8B04E0349C7828DF5D5B258B9CD }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_741E597FD19043F4B2CBF83B89C75D92 }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_ED0C3DE592084669926EEBA461FB5E98 }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'project-app-development'
          slot-name: 'Production'

Azure devops Yaml file :
trigger:
- $(feature-branch)

variables:
  azureServiceConnectionId: '-db5f-4993-91f8-85f3a75cb357'
  webAppName: 'project-app-development'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  environmentName: 'project-app-development'
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  pythonVersion: '3.8'
  system.debug: true

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        python -m virtualenv env
        source env/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: true
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : project-app-development'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip

Latest github actions error message :
##[debug]logs from kudu deploy: https://project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/temp-69fc3536/log
##[debug]setting affinity cookie ["ARRAffinity=f1c95587fdc6f942a20e5a5078e78322a753dff56e2f30cc9c09a2b930fa89ac;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net","ARRAffinitySameSite=f1c95587fdc6f942a20e5a5078e78322a753dff56e2f30cc9c09a2b930fa89ac;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net"]
##[debug][GET] https://project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/temp-69fc3536/log
##[debug]getDeploymentLogs. Data: {"statusCode":200,"statusMessage":"OK","headers":{"content-length":"268","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","date":"Mon, 19 Aug 2024 15:57:25 GMT","server":"Kestrel"},"body":[{"log_time":"2024-08-19T15:57:13.2195847Z","id":"afc2dd47-e1ad-4b07-b6aa-fb59b6531aad","message":"Fetching changes.","type":0,"details_url":"https://project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/temp-69fc3536/log/afc2dd47-e1ad-4b07-b6aa-fb59b6531aad"}]}
Fetching changes.
##[debug]setting affinity cookie ["ARRAffinity=f1c95587fdc6f942a20e5a5078e78322a753dff56e2f30cc9c09a2b930fa89ac;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net","ARRAffinitySameSite=f1c95587fdc6f942a20e5a5078e78322a753dff56e2f30cc9c09a2b930fa89ac;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net"]
##[debug][GET] https://project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/temp-69fc3536/log/afc2dd47-e1ad-4b07-b6aa-fb59b6531aad
##[debug]getDeploymentLogs. Data: {"statusCode":200,"statusMessage":"OK","headers":{"content-length":"274","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","date":"Mon, 19 Aug 2024 15:57:26 GMT","server":"Kestrel"},"body":[{"log_time":"2024-08-19T15:57:14.2281682Z","id":"","message":"Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/c28a10f3-d998-437f-94af-eed376d90b90.zip (24.85 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted","type":0,"details_url":null}]}
Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/c28a10f3-d998-437f-94af-eed376d90b90.zip (24.85 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed, Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
##[debug][POST] https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/project-app-development_group/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/project-app-development/config/appsettings/list?api-version=2016-08-01
##[debug][GET] https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/***/providers/microsoft.insights/components?$filter=InstrumentationKey eq '4f576d13-00e5-4831-a1d5-7e5ea3cab3c5'&api-version=2015-05-01
##[debug]Unable to find Application Insights resource with Instrumentation key 4f576d13-00e5-4831-a1d5-7e5ea3cab3c5. Skipping adding release annotation.
App Service Application URL: https://project-app-development.azurewebsites.net
##[debug]Deployment failed
##[debug]Node Action run completed with exit code 1
##[debug]AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT='GITHUBACTIONS_DeployWebAppToAzure_0a886200850ef7f915637c263559bb1d8963ef779ce24674d123a365c5ec1237'
##[debug]AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT=''
##[debug]Set output webapp-url = https://project-app-development.azurewebsites.net
##[debug]Finishing: Deploy to Azure Web App

Simpler error logs (Turned off advanced logs)
Run azure/webapps-deploy@v3
  
Package deployment using OneDeploy initiated.
{
  id: 'temp-fb83a24b',
  status: 3,
  status_text: '',
  author_email: 'N/A',
  author: 'N/A',
  deployer: 'OneDeploy',
  message: 'OneDeploy',
  progress: '',
  received_time: '2024-08-19T16:47:42.3127586Z',
  start_time: '2024-08-19T16:47:42.3127586Z',
  end_time: '2024-08-19T16:47:51.8169497Z',
  last_success_end_time: null,
  complete: true,
  active: false,
  is_temp: true,
  is_readonly: false,
  url: 'https://project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/temp-fb83a24b',
  log_url: 'https://project-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/temp-fb83a24b/log',
  site_name: 'project-app-development',
  build_summary: { errors: [], warnings: [] }
}
Fetching changes.
Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/31a79a90-85fe-4021-92a0-24cd5f24118d.zip (24.85 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed, Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
App Service Application URL: https://project-app-development.azurewebsites.net

When I set includeRootFolder : true, build does not fail, logs :
succesful but not working detailed logs 488
When I set includeRootFolder : false, build fails with the following, you can find the detailed logs here : failed detailed logs 489
Update : I am also trying with Github actions, the primary problem is : the zip file never arrives to Appservice from devops; either azure pipelines or github actions.
Change diff for "includeRootFolder : false" :
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
    includeRootFolder: true
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: zip
    archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
    replaceExistingArchive: true

Logs after setting "includeRootFolder : false" :
    ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
    ##[error]KuduStackTraceURL https://$project-app-development:***@videoo-app-development.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
    ##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.

Latest logs after setting

-includeRootFolder : false
-ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD : false
-SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT : true
-WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE : 1

2024-08-20T05:57:34.254Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2024-08-20T05:57:34.256Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8000 --name project-app-development_0_c5c7b0dd -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=false -e PORT=8000 -e WEBSITES_PORT=8000 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=project-app-development -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=project-app-development.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=3f627dbbecdaed255d87aa9c3e8f1448758df1cdff41f5e14b114384ea9b244a -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/python:3.8-bullseye_20240619.2.tuxprod
2024-08-20T05:57:35.308Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container project-app-development_0_c5c7b0dd for site project-app-development
2024-08-20T05:57:36.327Z ERROR - Container project-app-development_0_c5c7b0dd for site project-app-development has exited, failing site start
2024-08-20T05:57:36.334Z ERROR - Container project-app-development_0_c5c7b0dd didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-08-20T05:57:36.337Z INFO  - Stopping site project-app-development because it failed during startup.
2024-08-20T05:57:53.915425573Z    _____
2024-08-20T05:57:53.915485375Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____
2024-08-20T05:57:53.915492475Z  /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \
2024-08-20T05:57:53.915497675Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/
2024-08-20T05:57:53.915502375Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2024-08-20T05:57:53.915507176Z         \/      \/                  \/
2024-08-20T05:57:53.915511976Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2024-08-20T05:57:53.915516676Z
2024-08-20T05:57:53.915521376Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2024-08-20T05:57:53.915529576Z Python 3.8.19
2024-08-20T05:57:53.915536477Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2024-08-20T05:57:54.221285535Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2024-08-20T05:57:54.235160933Z WEBSITES_INCLUDE_CLOUD_CERTS is not set to true.
2024-08-20T05:57:54.265297413Z App Command Line not configured, will attempt auto-detect
2024-08-20T05:57:54.265793631Z Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite
2024-08-20T05:57:54.292483387Z Could not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2024-08-20T05:57:54.292508088Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2024-08-20T05:57:54.292513388Z Build Operation ID: b6e4f53f-a160-4836-81df-40a78959b714
2024-08-20T05:57:54.395411376Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20240619.2, Commit: cf006407a02b225f59dccd677986973c7889aa50, ReleaseTagName: 20240619.2
2024-08-20T05:57:54.398960704Z Detected an app based on Django
2024-08-20T05:57:54.399159411Z Generating `gunicorn` command for 'project.wsgi'
2024-08-20T05:57:54.410518018Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2024-08-20T05:57:54.427810538Z WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.
2024-08-20T05:57:54.427831338Z WARNING: Could not find package directory /home/site/wwwroot/__oryx_packages__.
2024-08-20T05:57:54.970237380Z [2024-08-20 05:57:54 +0000] [48] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 22.0.0
2024-08-20T05:57:54.987807809Z [2024-08-20 05:57:54 +0000] [48] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (48)
2024-08-20T05:57:54.987844111Z [2024-08-20 05:57:54 +0000] [48] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2024-08-20T05:57:54.997822968Z [2024-08-20 05:57:54 +0000] [57] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 57
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045597781Z [2024-08-20 05:57:55 +0000] [57] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045636382Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045643782Z   File "/opt/python/3.8.19/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045658983Z     worker.init_process()
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045664583Z   File "/opt/python/3.8.19/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045683084Z     self.load_wsgi()
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045688584Z   File "/opt/python/3.8.19/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045694184Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045699484Z   File "/opt/python/3.8.19/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045704784Z     self.callable = self.load()
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045710085Z   File "/opt/python/3.8.19/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045715485Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045720885Z   File "/opt/python/3.8.19/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045726285Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045731885Z   File "/opt/python/3.8.19/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045737786Z     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045743086Z   File "/opt/python/3.8.19/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045748486Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045753786Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045759786Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045765487Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045771387Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045776787Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045782087Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045787187Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045792588Z     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
2024-08-20T05:57:55.045797988Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
2024-08-20T05:57:55.046148100Z [2024-08-20 05:57:55 +0000] [57] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 57)
2024-08-20T05:57:55.107735008Z [2024-08-20 05:57:55 +0000] [48] [ERROR] Worker (pid:57) exited with code 3
2024-08-20T05:57:55.107770709Z [2024-08-20 05:57:55 +0000] [48] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
2024-08-20T05:57:55.107777009Z [2024-08-20 05:57:55 +0000] [48] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2024-08-20 05:57:54,978  [MainThread] [DEBUG] : Initializating AppServiceAppLogging
2024-08-20 05:57:54,982  [Thread-1  ] [DEBUG] : Did not find any previously bound socket
2024-08-20 05:57:54,983  [MainThread] [DEBUG] : Initialized AppServiceAppLogging
2024-08-20T05:57:53.623Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2024-08-20T05:57:53.641Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8000 --name project-app-development_0_4c6a7e4b -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=false -e PORT=8000 -e WEBSITES_PORT=8000 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=project-app-development -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=project-app-development.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=8a9506920697ea08e988fb00cb7a286fb2bda894a9cbfd61c5690d00f38d01a6 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/python:3.8-bullseye_20240619.2.tuxprod
2024-08-20T05:57:55.010Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container project-app-development_0_4c6a7e4b for site project-app-development
2024-08-20T05:57:56.129Z ERROR - Container project-app-development_0_4c6a7e4b for site project-app-development has exited, failing site start
2024-08-20T05:57:56.140Z ERROR - Container project-app-development_0_4c6a7e4b didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-08-20T05:57:56.145Z INFO  - Stopping site project-app-development because it failed during startup.


Hi can you check the path of  project.wsgi see whether it corresponds to where docker placed it. I am assumming you have a DockerFile.

No dockerfile, adding project.wsgi here on the ticket.

the zip file never arrives to Appservice from devops; either azure pipelines or github actions.   can you share more details about the issue? Do you mean that the files in Azure APP service not change after running pipeline? On the other hand, from the original description, you are getting the error in Azure Pipelines. Can you share your Pipeline definition instead of github action?

Based on the error message in original post, it seems that the port 8000 cannot connect. You can try to set the app settings: PORT  and  WEBSITES_PORT to 8000 in Azure App Service to expose the 8000 port. Then you can restart your App service and check if it can make some changes.

I have set both PORT and WEBSITES_PORT, nothing has changed.
I think the deployment is not correctly using the zip deployment and extracting on AppService on my case.

@london_utku  can you share the azure pipelines definition? Since the original description is related to azure DevOps pipeline

I tried all way, Azure Pipelines, Github Actions, App Service Deployment. Nothing is working. I have updated ticket with all related yaml files.

I have checked your Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline sample. It has some issues which will lead to the App service not able to work.
From the original log, it shows the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'. The cause of the issue is that the zip package doesn't contain the required python packages.
You can make the following changes to the Azure Pipeline YAML Sample:
1.You need to change the command to install python packages:
From
pip install -r requirements.txt

To
 pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt

In this case, the required packages will be installed to the correct folder and will be added to the zip pacakge.
2.You need to set the includeRootFolder field to false in ArchiveFiles@2 task.
If the value is set to true, it will include the parent folder : s to the zip package. This will cause the path issue in Web App. So we need to set the value to false.
Here is an example:
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: zip
    archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
    replaceExistingArchive: true

Full Pipeline YAML sample:
trigger:
- $(feature-branch)

variables:
  azureServiceConnectionId: '-db5f-4993-91f8-85f3a75cb357'
  webAppName: 'project-app-development'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  environmentName: 'project-app-development'
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  pythonVersion: '3.8'
  system.debug: true

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        python -m virtualenv env
        source env/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : project-app-development'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Use Azure Pipelines to build and deploy a Python web app to Azure App Service
Update:

Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.

Based on the error message, you can try the following methods:
1.Navigate to the App Settings in Azure Web App and set the variable: WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 1.
2.Navigate to App service --> Deployment Center, and click on the Disconnect button to disconnect the exist connections.
For example:

Then you can deploy the Azure Web App again and check the result.
Update1:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

I can reproduce the same issue in my Linux Web App.
To solve this issue, you can refer to the following steps:
Step1: Remove the variable: SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT in AppSettings of Azure Web App. In this case, it will directly used the existing packages in the zip package.
Step2: Change the pip install command:
From:
 pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt

To:
 pip install --target="./antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt

YAML Sample:
- script: |
   python -m venv antenv
   source antenv/bin/activate
   python -m pip install --upgrade pip
   pip install setup

   pip install --target="./antenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
  workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
  displayName: "Install requirements"

From the log in the Azure App service, the default Python Path: /home/site/wwwroot/antenv/lib/python3.8.9/site-packages. We need to adjust the path in the package to meet the default Python Path.
Then you can run the pipeline to deploy the web app again.

Comments are not for discussions - please stop abusing the comments section here (already over 50 comments). Also, comments are not for posting code, data, or any other formatted text - that belongs as edits to questions/answers. Lastly: please do not make commitments around responding or investigating - this is not a paid support channel - there is no such concept of SLA here either. If you must discuss this, move this to [chat].

@DavidMakogon; The information in those comments play a critical part in solving the issue in a step by steo manner. Can you just enable them, we can copy them, and then you can delete / disable them again. And wr can move them to stack overflow chat.

I didn't disable anything; a moderator removed the long chain of comments, as it turned into a tech support conversation (and I'm not a moderator - just a community member).

@kevin-lu-msft, the build takes about 20 minutes, is there any way to make it faster ?
